# JavasScript Add half a percent to a number any amount of times I choose

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Hi I need a block of code for some math that I'm trying to work out. The code I'm looking for will be able to add half a percent (0.005) to a number and return the result back to me. I need the code to take two separate inputs, the first is the start number, and the second is how many times I want the loop to execute. An example would be if I started with 7000 the code should output ~7321.37 (if possible let it stop after 2 decimal points). Thank you for the help in advance!

Code example of what I'm trying to do:

```
function growth(initialValue, timesOfExecution)` {
  let answer;
  let execute;
        while (execute > 0) {
        answer = initialValue + initialValue(0.05)
        execute--
         }
  return answer;
}
console.log(growth(7000, 9))
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack overflow. Please provide a code sample, what you've tried, what you've executed, what input you're using, what output you're expecting/getting, your research, etc. 
Please read [the guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to a good post.

If you're looking for someone to code for you maybe check out [fiver](https://www.fiverr.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
function growth(initialValue, timesOfExecution) {
  for (let i = 0; i < timesOfExecution; i++) {
    initialValue = initialValue + (initialValue * 0.005)
  }
  return initialValue.toFixed(2);
}

console.log(growth(7000, 9))
```